# How to change the message sent by the inline bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

There is this code:

```
@bot.inline_handler(lambda query: query.query == 'text')
def query_text(inline_query):
    try:
        
        r = types.InlineQueryResultArticle('1', 'text', types.InputTextMessageContent('2'))
        bot.answer_inline_query(inline_query.id, [r])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I do not understand how to make the message "2" be changed, for example, after 2 seconds to "3".
I wanted to do it through bot.edit_message_text () but I didn’t understand where to get all the id from.

Answer (score 0):

You get the `inline_message_id` parameter of `editMessageText` by listening for [`ChosenInlineResult`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#choseninlineresult) updates.

Also notice that you should do the following things to be able to receive updates like that:

- Contact [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather) and use the /setinlinefeedback command to enable receiving those updates.
- Add `chosen_inline_result` to the `allowed_updates` parameter when you [`getUpdates`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates).